# How to limit the display of rows in crystal report depending on a threshold value

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am new to StackOverflow and .net development. I am trying this requirement for one of my assignments.

I am using SQL server Management Studio express as the Database.
I have a table where I have columns named Serial Number and Amount.

## Payment Table

### Sl_No      Amount

```
1           100
2           200
3           100
4           200
.....       ....
```

In the UI page, user enters a threshold amount. 
For Ex: 350 is the threshold value

so when the crystal report generation button is clicked, The crystal report should display only the following rows in the first page since it is less than threshold value:

### Sl_No      Amount

```
1           100
2           200
```

In the next crystal report page, i want the next rows with the threshold value condition.
I have to limit the display of rows in the Crystal report as soon as the sum of the rows of Amount column cross the Threshold value.

### Sl_No      Amount

```
3           100
4           200
```

How can I achieve this? I tried searching in various forums. I tried with Format Formula editor in visual studio 2008.

Comment: your question is bit confusing.What exactly are you trying achieve?

Comment: @Appyks Is it more understandable now??

Answer (score 0):

In the "Section expert" select your Details section and create a formula for "New page After" using the threshold value